# Spaces in articles sources - Middleman

Tags: ruby, middleman

I have made a site using middleman-blog. My articles are stored like the following:

```
/source/entries/2012-01-01 - Example Article.md
```

But I am really struggling to set the sources. My Config.rb contains this

```
blog.sources = "entries/{year}-{month}-{day}\ -\ {title}"
blog.default_extension = ".md"
```

How are you meant to deal with spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces in filenames can be tough. The first thing I would try is to *not* escape the spaces - spaces need to be escaped in shell, but not in Ruby strings. So try this:

```
blog.sources = "entries/{year}-{month}-{day} - {title}"
```

Once you've done that, upgrade to middleman-blog 3.5+ - handling of spaces was a bug that's been fixed.

(Edited to reflect the status of the bug fix)